# Troubles extracting status picture with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Ok, so I am working on my own version of a thread unroller.
So far I've been able to extract the full text from the tweets, but where I'm stuck with is that most tweet come with an attached image, yet their `entities` field has no `media` attribute, such as this:

The code

```
status = api.get_status(tweet_id)

print("The status was created at : " + str(status.created_at))
print("The id is : " + str(status.id))
print("The id_str is : " + status.id_str)
print("The text is : " + status.text)
print("The entities are : " + str(status.entities))
print("The source is : " + status.source)
print("The source_url is : " + status.source_url)
```

The output

```
The status was created at : 2023-01-10 12:20:24+00:00
The id is : 1612786435324579841
The id_str is : 1612786435324579841
The text is : Confused about bonds and bond spreads? 
Why are these relevant to us as crypto and risk investors? 

Below I'll e… https://shortened-url
The entities are : {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': 'https://shortened-url', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1612786435324579841', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [117, 140]}]}
The source is : Twitter Web App
The source_url is : https://mobile.twitter.com
```

If you copy and paste the url at the end of the text it will open the entire tweet, yet in the entities field no image is mentioned.

I feel the answer is somewhere in the text url given that statuses without image thumbnail don't have the url at the end but admittedly my coding skills still leave to be desired.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweepy V2 can get it. It is more detail fine tunning.

Get Tweet by [`tweet ID`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id)

[image]

One of query parameter `media.fields` has `url` field.
[image]

This V2 API can get the image URL

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1612786435324579841/?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url
```

Result from Postman
[image]

Same idea using Tweepy v2

```
import tweepy

bearer_token ="your_token"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

tweet_id="1612786435324579841"
tweet_info = client.get_tweet(tweet_id, 
            media_fields=['url'],
            expansions=['attachments.media_keys']
            )

print(tweet_info.includes['media'][0].data)
```

```
$python get-url.py
{'media_key': '3_1612769009425842177', 'type': 'photo', 'url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FmG03oeWAAEjsBl.jpg'}
```

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to get used to as a newbie. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, tweet API supports a fine tunning after figuring out how works a detail parameter.